How to Center Navigation Arrows Vertically in a Shopify Slideshow Section?
I'm working on customizing a Shopify theme, and I'm having trouble centering the navigation arrows vertically in a slideshow section. The arrows are currently not aligned correctly, and I want them to be in the middle of the slideshow height. Here is the relevant Liquid and CSS code for the section I'm using:

{{ 'section-image-banner.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'component-slider.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'component-slideshow.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{%- if section.settings.slide_height == 'adapt_image' and section.blocks.first.settings.image != blank -%}
  {%- style -%}
    @media screen and (max-width: 749px) {
      #Slider-{{ section.id }}::before,
      #Slider-{{ section.id }} .media::before,
      #Slider-{{ section.id }}:not(.banner--mobile-bottom) .banner__content::before {
        padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.blocks.first.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
        content: '';
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
      #Slider-{{ section.id }}::before,
      #Slider-{{ section.id }} .media::before {
        padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.blocks.first.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
        content: '';
        display: block;
      }
    }
  {%- endstyle -%}
{%- endif -%}

<slideshow-component
  class="slider-mobile-gutter{% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %} page-width{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} mobile-text-below{% endif %}"
  role="region"
  aria-roledescription="{{ 'sections.slideshow.carousel' | t }}"
  aria-label="{{ section.settings.accessibility_info | escape }}"
>
  {%- if section.settings.auto_rotate and section.blocks.size > 1 -%}
    <div class="slideshow__controls slideshow__controls--top slider-buttons{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} slideshow__controls--border-radius-mobile{% endif %}">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="slider-button slider-button--prev"
        name="previous"
        aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.previous_slideshow' | t }}"
        aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
      >
        {% render 'icon-caret' %}
      </button>
      <div class="slider-counter slider-counter--{{ section.settings.slider_visual }}{% if section.settings.slider_visual == 'counter' or section.settings.slider_visual == 'numbers' %} caption{% endif %}">
        {%- if section.settings.slider_visual == 'counter' -%}
          <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
          <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ section.blocks.size }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          <div class="slideshow__control-wrapper">
            {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
              <button
                class="slider-counter__link slider-counter__link--{{ section.settings.slider_visual }} link"
                aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.load_slide' | t }} {{ forloop.index }} {{ 'general.slider.of' | t }} {{ forloop.length }}"
                aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
              >
                {%- if section.settings.slider_visual == 'numbers' -%}
                  {{ forloop.index -}}
                {%- else -%}
                  <span class="dot"></span>
                {%- endif -%}
              </button>
            {%- endfor -%}
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="slider-button slider-button--next"
        name="next"
        aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.next_slideshow' | t }}"
        aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
      >
        {% render 'icon-caret' %}
      </button>

      {%- if section.settings.auto_rotate -%}
        <button
          type="button"
          class="slideshow__autoplay slider-button{% if section.settings.auto_rotate == false %} slideshow__autoplay--paused{% endif %}"
          aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}"
        >
          {%- render 'icon-pause' -%}
          {%- render 'icon-play' -%}
        </button>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}

  <div
    class="slideshow banner banner--{{ section.settings.slide_height }} grid grid--1-col slider slider--everywhere{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} banner--mobile-bottom{% endif %}{% if section.blocks.first.settings.image == blank %} slideshow--placeholder{% endif %}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--fade-in{% endif %}"
    id="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
    aria-live="polite"
    aria-atomic="true"
    data-autoplay="{{ section.settings.auto_rotate }}"
    data-speed="{{ section.settings.change_slides_speed }}"
  >
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
      <style>
        #Slide-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }} .banner__media::after {
          opacity: {{ block.settings.image_overlay_opacity | divided_by: 100.0 }};
        }
      </style>
      <div
        class="slideshow__slide grid__item grid--1-col slider__slide"
        id="Slide-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }}"
        {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
        role="group"
        aria-roledescription="{{ 'sections.slideshow.slide' | t }}"
        aria-label="{{ forloop.index }} {{ 'general.slider.of' | t }} {{ forloop.length }}"
        tabindex="-1"
      >
        <div class="slideshow__media banner__media media{% if block.settings.image == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_behavior != 'none' %} animate--{{ section.settings.image_behavior }}{% endif %}">
          {%- if block.settings.image -%}
            {%- liquid
              assign height = block.settings.image.width | divided_by: block.settings.image.aspect_ratio | round
              if section.settings.image_behavior == 'ambient'
                assign sizes = '120vw'
                assign widths = '450, 660, 900, 1320, 1800, 2136, 2400, 3600, 7680'
              else
                assign sizes = '100vw'
                assign widths = '375, 550, 750, 1100, 1500, 1780, 2000, 3000, 3840'
              endif
              assign fetch_priority = 'auto'
              if section.index == 1
                assign fetch_priority = 'high'
              endif
            -%}
            {%- if forloop.first %}
              {{
                block.settings.image
                | image_url: width: 3840
                | image_tag: height: height, sizes: sizes, widths: widths, fetchpriority: fetch_priority
              }}
            {%- else -%}
              {{
                block.settings.image
                | image_url: width: 3840
                | image_tag: loading: 'lazy', height: height, sizes: sizes, widths: widths
              }}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- else -%}
            {%- assign placeholder_slide = forloop.index | modulo: 2 -%}
            {%- if placeholder_slide == 1 -%}
              {{ 'hero-apparel-2' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            {%- else -%}
              {{ 'hero-apparel-1' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- endif -%}
        </div>
       
      </div>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>







  
  {%- if section.blocks.size > 1 and section.settings.auto_rotate == false -%}
    <div class="slideshow__controls slider-buttons{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} slideshow__controls--border-radius-mobile{% endif %}">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="slider-button slider-button--prev"
        name="previous"
        aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.previous_slideshow' | t }}"
        aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
      >
        {% render 'icon-caret' %}
      </button>
      <div class="slider-counter slider-counter--{{ section.settings.slider_visual }}{% if section.settings.slider_visual == 'counter' or section.settings.slider_visual == 'numbers' %} caption{% endif %}">
        {%- if section.settings.slider_visual == 'counter' -%}
          <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
          <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ section.blocks.size }}</span>
        {%- else -%}
          <div class="slideshow__control-wrapper">
            {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
              <button
                class="slider-counter__link slider-counter__link--{{ section.settings.slider_visual }} link"
                aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.load_slide' | t }} {{ forloop.index }} {{ 'general.slider.of' | t }} {{ forloop.length }}"
                aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
              >
                {%- if section.settings.slider_visual == 'numbers' -%}
                  {{ forloop.index -}}
                {%- else -%}
                  <span class="dot"></span>
                {%- endif -%}
              </button>
            {%- endfor -%}
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="slider-button slider-button--next"
        name="next"
        aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.next_slideshow' | t }}"
        aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
      >
        {% render 'icon-caret' %}
      </button>

      {%- if section.settings.auto_rotate -%}
        <button
          type="button"
          class="slideshow__autoplay slider-button{% if section.settings.auto_rotate == false %} slideshow__autoplay--paused{% endif %}"
          aria-label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}"
        >
          {%- render 'icon-pause' -%}
          {%- render 'icon-play' -%}
        </button>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}


{%- style -%}
  .slideshow__controls {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Center horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
  }

  .slider-button--prev, .slider-button--next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .slider-button--prev {
    left: 10px; /* Adjust this value to position the left arrow */
  }

  .slider-button--next {
    right: 10px; /* Adjust this value to position the right arrow */
  }
{%- endstyle -%}


  
</slideshow-component>

{%- if request.design_mode -%}
  <script src="{{ 'theme-editor.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
{%- endif -%}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.slideshow.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "section",
  "disabled_on": {
    "groups": ["header", "footer"]
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "layout",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "full_bleed",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.layout.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "grid",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.layout.options__2.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "full_bleed",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.layout.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "slide_height",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "adapt_image",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slide_height.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "small",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slide_height.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "medium",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slide_height.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "large",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slide_height.options__4.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "medium",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slide_height.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "slider_visual",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "dots",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slider_visual.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "counter",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slider_visual.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "numbers",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slider_visual.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "counter",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.slider_visual.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "auto_rotate",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.auto_rotate.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "change_slides_speed",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 9,
      "step": 2,
      "unit": "s",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.change_slides_speed.label",
      "default": 5
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.all.animation.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_behavior",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "none",
          "label": "t:sections.all.animation.image_behavior.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "ambient",
          "label": "t:sections.all.animation.image_behavior.options__2.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "none",
      "label": "t:sections.all.animation.image_behavior.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.mobile.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_text_below",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.show_text_below.label",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.accessibility.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "accessibility_info",
      "label": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.accessibility.label",
      "info": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.accessibility.info",
      "default": "Slideshow about our brand"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "slide",
      "name": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.name",
      "limit": 5,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.image.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "inline_richtext",
          "id": "heading",
          "default": "Image slide",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.heading.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "heading_size",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "h2",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h1",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h0",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "h1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "inline_richtext",
          "id": "subheading",
          "default": "Tell your brand's story through images",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.subheading.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label",
          "default": "Button label",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.button_label.label",
          "info": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.button_label.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "link",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.link.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "button_style_secondary",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.secondary_style.label",
          "default": false
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "box_align",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "top-left",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "top-center",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "top-right",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__3.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "middle-left",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__4.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "middle-center",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__5.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "middle-right",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__6.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "bottom-left",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__7.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "bottom-center",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__8.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "bottom-right",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.options__9.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "middle-center",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.label",
          "info": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.box_align.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "show_text_box",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.show_text_box.label",
          "default": true
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_alignment",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "left",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment.option_1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "center",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment.option_2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "right",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment.option_3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "range",
          "id": "image_overlay_opacity",
          "min": 0,
          "max": 100,
          "step": 10,
          "unit": "%",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.image_overlay_opacity.label",
          "default": 0
        },
        {
          "type": "color_scheme",
          "id": "color_scheme",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.label",
          "default": "scheme-1"
        },
        {
          "type": "header",
          "content": "t:sections.slideshow.settings.mobile.content"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_alignment_mobile",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "left",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment_mobile.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "center",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment_mobile.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "right",
              "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment_mobile.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.slideshow.blocks.slide.settings.text_alignment_mobile.label"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.slideshow.presets.name",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "slide"
        },
        {
          "type": "slide"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}



This is how it looks now: This is how it looks now
This is how it should look: This is how it should look
Despite all of the modifications I made, the arrows are not centered vertically within the slideshow. What am I doing wrong?
Additional Information:

The section has a setting for the height of the slides which could be affecting the centering of the arrows.

Any advice on how to properly center the navigation arrows vertically within the slideshow would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

way too much text and "unnecessary noise" for the question of how to vertically center an element. Especially the entire code for the component is unnecessary. All you would need to make the question readable and short would be to post the code for the container and the arrow button. There are many different solutions with the top 2 being flexbox and absolute positioning with 50% offset.

@tacoshy, very helpful, thank you! :(

Ask yourself why no one tried to help you yet. They don't want to read up how to compile your component, then compile it to have the DOM to be able to help you. Give them informations they can actually work with in the form of compiled HTML and CSS. It is a basic CSS issue that you overcomplicate by posting u compiled code

@tacoshy, you are right, thank you! :)

For slideshows I like to use pseudo-elements for the arrows, positioned absolutely within the slideshow container.


const ss = document.querySelector('.slideshow')

const next = (n) => {
  const x = ss.querySelector('.visible')
  x.classList.remove('visible')
  const y = Array.from(ss.children)
  const z = y.indexOf(x)
  let i = null
  if (n) i = z == y.length - 1 ? 0 : z + 1
  else i = z == 0 ? y.length - 1 : z - 1
  y[i].classList.add('visible')
}

ss.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const rect = ss.getBoundingClientRect()
  const mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left
  next(mouseX > rect.width / 2)
})
.slideshow {
  width: 360px;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow::before, .slideshow::after {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 0 5px 2px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5);
}

.slideshow::before {
  content: '<';
  left: 3px;
}

.slideshow::after {
  content: '>';
  right: 3px;
}

.slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.slideshow img.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
<div class="slideshow">

  <img class="visible" src="http://picsum.photos/id/655/400/200">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/639/500/250">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/670/500/250">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/674/500/250">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/696/500/250">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/715/500/250">

</div>



